# Can pandas read and archive within an archive?

Tags: python, pandas, tarfile

I have an archive file (archive.tar.gz) which contains multiple archive files (file.txt.gz).

If I first extract the .txt.gz files to a folder, I can then open them with pandas directly using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt.gz', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

But if I explore the archive using the tarfile library, then it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("archive.tar.gz", "r:*")
csv_path = tar.getnames()[1]
df = pd.read_csv(tar.extractfile(csv_path), sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the file by filename, then Pandas will be able to *infer* that it is compressed with gzip due to the `*.gz` extension on the filename.

When you pass it a file object, you need to tell it explicitly about the compression so that it can decompress it as it reads the file.

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    tar.extractfile(csv_path),
    compression='gzip',
    sep='\t',
    encoding='utf-8')
```

For more details, see the entry about the "compression" argument in the documentation for [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` is probably trying to interpret the input as a filename. If you wrap the extracted file in `io.BytesIO`, I suspect you should be able to get it to treat it as it would an open file handle

```
from io import BytesIO
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(tar.extractfile(csv_path)), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It takes a while for it to fail but it gives "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ExFileObject'"

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I had the same requirement and the following solution works. Two small changes - you have to read the extracted file `tar.extractfile(xx).read()` and pass it to `BytesIO()`:

```
from io import BytesIO

tar = tarfile.open("archive.tar.gz", "r:gz")
csv_path = tar.getnames()[1]
csv_bytes = BytesIO(tar.extractfile(csv_path).read())
df = pd.read_csv(csv_bytes, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```